# Group extension reference request

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I'm looking for a reference for the following "well known" result

Let  $C$ be an abelian group and $G$ a finite group, and  let $$0 \rightarrow C \rightarrow W \rightarrow G \rightarrow 0$$ be a group extension of $G$ by $C$ corresponding to the fundamental class in $H^2(C,G)$. Now the result I have says that if we have a homomorphism $f$ from $C$ to some abelian group  $A$ and an exact sequence of groups $$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \rtimes G  \rightarrow G \rightarrow 0, $$ then you can extend $f$ to some map $$f': W \rightarrow A' \rtimes G$$ such that both these sequences fit into a commutative diagram with the first vertical arrow given by $f$ and the third given by the identity map if and only if $f$ is $G$ invariant and it "sends" (I don't quite get what this means) the fundamental class in $H^2(C,G)$ to zero.

The place I got this result from just gives a reference to Serre's Local fields but not a page number or anything that might narrow where this result is. I can imagine it is pretty standard but I cant seem to find anything of this sort.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had better suppose that $A$ is abelian, and so a $G$-module; otherwise I'm not sure the question makes sense (because the $H^2$ with coeffs. in $A$ would not be defined).

Group cohom. is functorial in the coefficients, so $C \to A$ induces
$f_*: H^2(G,C) \to H^2(G,A)$.  This latter map has an interpretation in terms of
extensions: it sends the extension $0 \to C \to W \to G \to 0$ to the
extension $0 \to A \to W' \to G \to 0$ obtained by "pushing out" along the
morphism $C \to A$.  One way to think about $W'$ is that it is the unique extension of $G$ by $A$ compatible with given action of $G$ on $A$, and which
receives a map from $W$ that restricts to $f$ on $C$ and induces the identity on $G$.

Now by definition the $0$ class in $H^2$ corresponds to the split extension,
i.e. the semi-direct product.  Thus $f_*$ sends the class of $W$ (an element of $H^2G,C)$) to zero in $H^2(G,A)$
if and only if $W'$ is a semidirect product.

Now if you think about the above description of the push-out, you will see that $W'$ equals
the semidirect product if and only if $W$ admits a map to the semidirect product, compatibly with the given map $f: C \to A$ and the identity on $G$.

Comment: Ah great I see what you mean, do you know of a good place to get a refence for this? Thank you

Comment: and yes $A$ is abelian, forgot to mention that

Comment: @Chris: Dear Chris, Maybe MacLane's book on homology?  But it's absolutely standard, and follows directly from the basic definitions and constructions, so I don't know if you'll find people writing it down as an explicit statement that you can reference; more likely you will just find them using it without too much fuss and bother.  Regards,

Comment: yeah I see what you mean, thank you very much for your help :)